# 80 bit floating point arithmetic in C/C++

Tags: c, compiler-construction, floating-point-precision

Let assume a, `b` are `_int64` variables.
Need to calculate `sqrt((long double)a)*sqrt((long double)b)` in high precision 80 bit floating point.

Example. `(__int64)(sqrt((long double)a)*sqrt((long double)a) + 0.5) != a` in many cases as should be.

Which win32 C/C++ compiler can manage 80 bit floating point arithmetic?

Comment: C **or** C++ compiler? Choose *one* or explicitly say you need both.

Comment: `long double sqrtl(long double x);`

Comment: WTP: Can be C or C++ compiler for win32 / amd64. Does not matter for me.

Comment: Your question uses both `_int64` (one underbar) and `__int64` (two underbars).  If this is intentional, what is the difference / meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should not be using floating point to take the square root of an integer, especially `long double` which is poorly supported and might have an approximate (not accurate) `sqrtl` on some systems. Instead look up integer square root algorithms.

Comment: It is more difficult. I am searching for solutions system of diofant equations (lim. to 64 bit integers). The form of INTEGER NUMBER sqrtl(a)*sqrtl(b) is most simple representation of possible solution.

Comment: I mean there are ways you can perform square roots on integers directly without using floating point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that sqrt() is valid for long doubles?

At least in some environments sqrt() is for doubles, sqrtf() for floats and sqrtl() for long doubles.

Comment: Yes. math.h has version: long double sqrt(long double)

Comment: The `sqrt()` function declared in `<math.h>` is definitely for doubles, not for long double; `sqrtl()` is for long doubles.  But there's also a "type-generic macro" `sqrt()` defined in `<tgmath.h>` (if your compiler supports it, it's a relatively new feature).

Comment: @amuliar: It's called "sqrtl", not "sqrt".

Comment: Open Watcom C/C++ compiler has only sqrt version. :(

Answer (score 1):

Embarcadero's C++Builder will handle 80 bit floating point. Use the long double type, or the (imported from Delphi) Extnded type. They are the same.

Comment: Yes it has 80 bit, but it fails.
a = 8642673492431640625L;
Result in Delphi: 8642673492431640624. Borland C++ Compiler 5.5: 8642673492431640200

Comment: OK, I just tried:    `unsigned __int64 a = 8642673492431640625L;
    long double ld = a;
    printf("%0.1Lf\n", ld);` and it prints: `8642673492431640625.0`, which seems correct, to me. That was in C++Builder XE.